# Android - onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with an image view and text view for each list element, as per the screenshot below. The image and text views together make the clickable element so if you tap to the right of any text nothing happens, you have to tap on the text or image. How do I make the link span the width of the whole list element, basically to the right hand edge of the screen?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:gravity="center|right"
    android:src="@drawable/image5" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:gravity="center|right" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your item xml data.

Comment: if mListView is your ListView instance then try to call this:

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

fix the errors then define your action in the onItemClick() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Parent Layout `width` and `height` as `match_parent`/`fill_parent`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:gravity="center|right"
    android:src="@drawable/image5" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:gravity="center|right" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I made a typing error. That's going to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your listview item layout, set the width of `textview` to `0dp` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute to `textview`.

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
     android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
  android:gravity="center|right" >
    </TextView>

Comment: The two lines you suggested haven't made any difference unfortunately.

Comment: what is the width of your root layout..??

Comment: I've added my layout xml file.

Comment: set your linear layout width to fill parent

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this inside your Adapters getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View vi = convertView;
   if(convertView==null) { ... }
   ...
   vi.setOnClickListener(new OnListItemClickListener(position));
   return vi;
}

private class OnListItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

   private int mPosition;

   OnListItemClickListener(int pos) {

      this.mPosition = pos;
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {

      //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH YOUR "CLICK". THE POSITION CLICKED IS STORED INSIDE mPosition.
   }
}
```